# Can Thrust::sort/unique handle NaN, Inf?

Tags: pointers, parallel-processing, cuda, thrust

In my CUDA Kernel:

```
// declaring data
float * data = new float[size];
[...]
[fill data]
[...]

// sorting
thrust::sort(data, data + size, thrust::greater<float>());

// unique
thrust::unique(thrust::device, data, data + size);
```

Output:

```
data =

0.1000
0.1000
0.1000
     0
-0.3000
-0.2000
-0.1000
-Inf
-Inf
-Inf
NaN
Inf
Inf
Inf
-Inf
-Inf  
NaN
Inf
Inf
Inf
Inf
```

My output, which you can here see in MATLAB is not sorted and the duplicates are not removed. UNIQUE and SORT isn't working at all. Is an pointer to array not supported for Thrust?

Comment: It is impossible to sort IEEE754 NaN values because (by definition) NaN is incomparable. The standard C++ comparison operators (and its thrust equivalent) cannot compare NaN to other numbers or itself.

Answer (score 2):

No comparison based algorithm can work correctly with data containing `NaN` values, because `NaN` is [uncomparable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/681865). `Inf` and `-Inf` are comparable, and will work with thrust or C++ standard library algorithms which perform comparison.

The only solution here is to firstly remove the `NaN` values (`thrust::remove_if` can be used for this with a functor or lambda expression which uses `isnan`), then run comparison based algorithms on the data. So something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

int main()
{
    const int N=18;
    unsigned int data[N] = { 
         0x3e99999a, 0x7f800000, 0xff800000, 0x7fffffff, 0x3e4ccccd, 0x3dcccccd, 
         0x3e99999a, 0x7f800000, 0xff800000, 0x7fffffff, 0x3e4ccccd, 0x3dcccccd, 
         0x3e99999a, 0x7f800000, 0xff800000, 0x7fffffff, 0x3e4ccccd, 0x3dcccccd };

    float* input = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&data[0]);

    {
        std::cout << "Input" << std::endl;
        auto it = input;
        for(; it != input+N; ++it) { std::cout << *it << std::endl; }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    auto pred = [](const float& v){ return isnan(v); };
    auto input_end = thrust::remove_if(input, input+N, pred);
    thrust::sort(input, input_end);
    input_end = thrust::unique(input, input_end);

    {
        std::cout << "Output" << std::endl;
        auto it = input;
        for(; it != input_end; ++it) {std::cout << *it << std::endl; }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which does the following:

```
~/SO$ nvcc --std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 inf_nan.cu 
~/SO$ ./a.out 
Input
0.3
inf
-inf
nan
0.2
0.1
0.3
inf
-inf
nan
0.2
0.1
0.3
inf
-inf
nan
0.2
0.1

Output
-inf
0.1
0.2
0.3
inf
```

is perfectly capable of sorting and extracting unique values, include `Inf` and `-Inf` on the input data once the `NaN` entries are removed.